# JCDatePopup inside a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, popup, jdialog

I am trying to open a `date picker` popup inside a jdialog. When I do it inside a panel, it is working fine. But when I do it within a dialog, the Date picker gets open beside the Dialog because of which I can able to see the picker if I move the dialog to other place but I am unable to select the date as the dialog is on top of it. Somebody please help me out of this.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Also which date picker